# Is it possible to fully use graphics card in Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, hyper-v

I have i7 3770 with Intel® HD Graphics 4000. I want to run games in Virtual Machine. Most of them show errors with DirectX and Direct3D, but such games work fine on host machine.

I tried VirtualBox, Vmware, Hyper-V.

Also tried 3D acceleration and RemoteFX.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with ESXi, check out this KB: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1010789